# Google Maps API token/authentication

Tags: google-api, google-places-api

Google Maps API provides an [Autocomplition service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform).

According to [this](http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.co.uk/2012/05/faster-address-entry-with-google-places.html) blog post (official?) this service is limited only by adding "powered by Google" logo.

When I'm using js library (http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places) I'm not sending any Key information. But in a sniffer I can see some *token* GET parameter, which seems is generated by library.

1. Which one limitation information is correct?
2. How Google can track without Key (in case it is limited by requests per day)?
3. Is that possible to retrieve autosuggestion by js (from *google.maps.places.Autocomplete*), but then using reference (without storing) on backend and loading place details (similar to *getPlace()* functionality of an Autocomplete object)? If this not limited, how to generate token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Google Places API Web Service](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/usage)

> The Google Places API Web Service enforces a default limit of 1 000
>   requests per 24 hour period, which you can increase free of charge. If
>   your app exceeds the limit, the app will start failing. Verify your
>   identity to get up to 150 000 requests per 24 hour period, by enabling
>   billing on the Google Developers Console.

Now check at the very top of that page

> Note: These limits **do not** apply to the Places Library in the Google
>   Maps **JavaScript API**, which is covered by the Google Maps JavaScript
>   API limits. If you are developing a web based application that only
>   needs to search for places, and does not submit new places, you should
>   use the Places Library of the Google Maps Javascript API rather than
>   the Google Places API Web Service. The Places library assigns a quota
>   to each end user rather than to each key. This means that your
>   available quota increases with your user base rather than being capped
>   at a fixed amount.

they are probably using ip address to identify different users.

Comment: I think it's not so easy to identify by IP address. because a lot Internet Provider use NAT. So In case I'm using web interface with JS for location autocompletion and place details retrievement - it's free. thanks